# SolrException: Cannot unload non-existent core

Tags: solr

I have just installed Sc9.3 using SIA and browsed the Solr page.
In the Logging section, I see all these errors.
I'm able to browse the CMS though.

How can I fix these errors or can they be ignored.

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot unload non-existent core
>   [local.mysite.com_xdb]
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot
>   unload non-existent core [local.mysite.com_xdb_rebuild]
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot unload non-existent core
>   [local.mysite.com_core_index]
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Cannot unload non-existent core [local.mysite.com_master_index]
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot unload non-existent core
>   [local.mysite.com_web_index]
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Cannot unload non-existent core
>   [local.mysite.com_marketingdefinitions_master]
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot unload non-existent core
>   [local.mysite.com_marketingdefinitions_web]
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot unload non-existent core
>   [local.mysite.com_marketing_asset_index_master]
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot unload non-existent core
>   [local.mysite.com_marketing_asset_index_web]
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot unload non-existent core
>   [local.mysite.com_testing_index] 
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Cannot unload non-existent core
>   [local.mysite.com_suggested_test_index]
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot unload non-existent core
>   [local.mysite.com_fxm_master_index]
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot unload non-existent core
>   [local.mysite.com_fxm_web_index] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Cannot unload non-existent core
>   [local.mysite.com_personalization_index]
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR:
>   [doc=sitecore://master/{7356f179-b8d2-4091-ac17-d65f02e4416d}?lang=en&ver=1&ndx=sitecore_master_index] unknown field 'schedule_t_en'
>    org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   ERROR:
>   [doc=sitecore://master/{7317161b-c430-4fa5-87cf-5cc4d46995f5}?lang=en&ver=1&ndx=sitecore_master_index] unknown field 'schedule_t_en' org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   ERROR:
>   [doc=sitecore://master/{a6599689-3616-4938-a5bb-9ec65480d2f3}?lang=en&ver=1&ndx=sitecore_master_index] unknown field 'schedule_t_en'

Comment: Could you check in Solr admin panel if the cores in question exist?

Comment: @grg. They are present in the `Core Selector` dropdown. Is that what you asked.
Strangely, I do not see any errors now after a system restart.

Comment: good to know. It might have been Solr hiccup.